# Azure DevOps counter expressions not working as expected

Tags: azure-devops, expression

I'm trying to create a counter expression like so

```
variables:
  internalBuildNumber: 1
  semanticBuildNumber: $[counter(variables['internalBuildNumber'], 0)]
```

The problem is that the counter expression seems to be only expanded when the job starts. I have a powershell script that sets the internalBuildNumber

```
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=internalBuildNumber]$version"
```

I then intend to use the combination of this internalBuildNumber and semanticBuildNumber to update the build number of the build

```
powershell: echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(internalBuildNumber).$(semanticBuildNumber)"
```

For example I expect the following:
First run:

- internalBuildNumber set to 1.1.0-alpha1 via powershell script
- semanticBuildNumber when evaluated should result in 0
- build number would be set to 1.1.0-alpha1.0

Second run:

- internalBuildNumber is set to 1.1.0-alpha2 via powershell script because new commit was done
- semanticBuildNumber when evaluate should result in 0
- build number would be set to 1.1.0-alpha2.0

However, on second run the counter is set to 1 and just keeps increasing with every run making me think that is not being evaluated based on the set value of internalBuildNumber but rather the initial value of it.

Hopefully I what I'm saying makes sense. Is this what the expectation is?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure DevOps counter expressions not working as expected

Actually, the Azure DevOps counter expressions works as expected.

The reason why it not work for you is that you do not distinguish between runtime variables and predefined variables.

You have define the variables `internalBuildNumber` and `semanticBuildNumber` in the Varivales tab, which are predefined variables.

When you overwrite the variable `internalBuildNumber` by the value `$version`. Now the variable `internalBuildNumber` is a runtime variable, it works in the environment, where you task running. **However**, it does not affect the predefined variable, which is out of current environment.

On the other words, the Overwritten variable `internalBuildNumber` will only work in the agent, it does not change the value you defined in the web portal. When we started running our pipeline for the second time, the pipeline still gets the predefined variables, it can't get the variables from the last closed environment.

That is the reason why you second run the counter is set to 1 and just keeps increasing based on the initial value of it.

To resolve this issue, you need to set the counter based on the value of the `$version` instead of `internalBuildNumber`.